# Javascript and DOM - insertBefore Only Excutes Once

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a simple script that copies a table row to a global javascript variable *(I know using global variables are not a great idea in javascript, but this is only for development)* and a function that inserts a copy of the row on an "onClick" event.

It executes and inserts a row. The problem is that it will only insert a row ONCE.

Here is a sample table

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr id="copyRow">
            <td>Sample Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="javascript:void();" onClick="insertRow(copy_row, this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode)">Insert Row</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my sample javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    copy_row = document.getElementByID('copyRow').cloneNode(true); //Runs when page first runs

    function insertRow(insertRow, insertBeforeMe){
     insertBeforeMe.parentNode.insertBefore(insertRow, insertBeforeMe)  
    }
</script>
```

I'm stumped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clone the node each time the insertRow function is called, so that you get a new copy of element instead recycling the one cloned row.

```
copy_row = document.getElementByID('copyRow'); //Runs when page first runs

function insertRow(insertRow, insertBeforeMe){
 insertBeforeMe.parentNode.insertBefore(insertRow.cloneNode(true), insertBeforeMe)  
}
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you. Do you have any idea why recycling the object would cause the script to fail?

Comment: You're welcome. I think recycling (inserting the same element again) will in effect remove the element from it's current parent, and insert it again to a different place (or maybe to exactly the same place, in your case). It will not get automatically copied/duplicated, so you are handling (removing and inserting) the same single element instance all the time. You need the cloneNode at proper place to create new rows/elements.

Comment: Ah! That makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't even run once. JavaScript is case sensitive, so you must use:

```
document.getElementById
```

Not

```
document.getElementByID
```

Here is my [working version of your script](http://jsfiddle.net/eGY8V/).